# request object in express server does not persist

Tags: passport.js

I am using passportjs (google/facebook strategy) to login. What I observed is that the req.session (from express-session) is updated with 'passport.user' key after logging in via the social channels (using serialize user). This is fine.

What I expected was that if the next http request is made then in that the req.session would still contain the passport.user key, but that does not happen. So I had to store the session in mongodb via mongo-connect. Now in the mongo store I have the session information present.

Is this normal behaviour? That req object does not persist in between two http request to the same express server instance? So every time a new request has to be made the session has to be retrieved from the mongo store.

It begs the question, if the above behaviour of req.session is true, why do we need deserializeUser ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you setup your app to use Passport's session middleware?

```
// Configuring Passport
var passport = require('passport');
var expressSession = require('express-session');

app.use(session({ secret: 'secret'}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

I am building a web app and using passport local strategy. Once you have successfully authenticated, the user information is added to the session and remain their till the time it is deleted from the session (during logout).